# Prolog - Why is my member returning false?

Tags: prolog, member

still very new to Prolog.

I am trying to see if one of my genres is part of my returned list using member, but I get false.

This is what I've got:

```
test(G) :- findall(G,(book(_,_,G,_)),A),
           flatten(A,L),
           member(G,L).
```

and when testing I get a false (using `test(g1).`).

However, when I test without member, the flatten gives me the following list:

```
L = [g3, g4, g1, g5, g2, g1, g3, g4].
```

so g1 *is* part of L, and to my comprehension should return true?

Comment: In Prolog a variable by a given name represents the same thing throughout the predicate. So your `G` in `findall(G,(book(_,_,G,_)),A)` is the same `G` that's in `member(G, L)` and is the same `G` in the call `test(G)`. When you run `test(g1)` you are calling `findall(g1,(book(_,_,g1,_)),A)`. Which will result in `A` being loaded with as many `g1` instances as the number of times `book(_,_,g1,_)` succeeds. Solution: do not re-use `G` in your `findall/3` that should be its own variable for that purpose.

Comment: Please post all the code, including `flatten/2` and `book/4` (unless renaming the vars solve it).

Comment: @TomasBy updated my comment as I didn't read the question carefully on how the OP did the query. The `findall` may fail or it may provide a list, `A`, consisting of one or more `g1`s.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Thanks lurker! I've been at it for over 2 hours trying various combinations. Prolog is not intuitive to me, unfortunately. Changing the variable G to something else from test(G) and member(G,L) returns true.

Comment: The easiest way to learn Prolog is to forget about what you know of other programming languages. That will get you a long way. Beginners get in trouble as soon as they start thinking that Prolog works like C or any other imperative language. Prolog behavioral rules are fairly simple, but not at all like other common languages.

Comment: Also, is there a material difference between your `test/1` and `test(G) :- book(_, _, G, _).`? Or `test(G) :- book(_, _, G0, _), member(G, G0).`?